# Filtro en adapter personalizado con edit text

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Buenas tardes amigos hoy necesito de su ayuda tengo un adapter personalizado con un edittext donde el usuario puede filtrar la lista y en el item de la lista hay un edittext donde capturo una cantidad, el problema es que la lista me la filtra pero digito la cantidad y se queda pegado el valor en la posición de la lista.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

Adapter:

public class ProductoAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder> {

```
private Context mCtx;
private List<Producto> productos;
//private static ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList;
private int selected_position = 0;

public ProductoAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Producto> productos) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.productos = productos;
    //ProductoAdapter.editModelArrayList = editModelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull 
ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_det_pedido,null);
    return  new ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductoViewHolder holder, int 
position) {

    if((position % 2) == 0)
        
holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c1c9d0"));
    else
        
holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0e72a4"));

    Producto producto = productos.get(position);
    holder.tvNombre.setText(producto.getNombre());
    holder.tvComponente.setText(producto.getP_activo());
    holder.tvPresentacion.setText(producto.getPresentacion());
    holder.etCantidad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int 
i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, 
int i2) {

            productos.get(position).setCantidad(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

//holder.etCantidad.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue());

```
}

public List<Producto> getList()
{
    return this.productos;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (productos != null)
        return productos.size();
    return 0;
}
```

class ProductoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
View.OnClickListener{

```
TextView tvNombre,  tvComponente, tvPresentacion;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
EditText etCantidad;

public ProductoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyDetPro);
    tvNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomProducto);
    tvComponente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvComProducto);
    tvPresentacion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPreProducto);
    etCantidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etCantidad);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

}

```
public void filtrar(List<Producto> filtroProductos) {
    this.productos = filtroProductos;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su colaboracion

Comment: Se queda pegado, te refieres a que se replica el valor en los demas productos?

Answer (score 1):

Define en el TextView únicamente el valor cantidad del objeto Carro:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CarroViewHolder holder, final int position) {
...
...
  Carro carro = productList.get(position);
...
   holder.tvCantidad.setText(carro.getCantidad());
...
...
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que sucede es que me equivoque de adaptador, tratare de colocar el correcto o abrire una nueva pregunta gracias